# Component disappears when adding a new controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

New to AngularJS and currently working on an introductory project to get me familiar with the technology.

I've based my application on the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project that uses ngRoute to show components depending on what link is followed. I have a component, pageHeader, that I'm using to define the links at the top of the page:

```
angular.
  module('DataStructureVisualizer').
  component('pageHeader', {
    template:
      '<div id="header">' + 
      '<center>' + 
        '<a href="#!/BinaryTree">Binary Tree</a>' + 
        '<a href="#!/Stack">Stack</a>' + 
        '<a href="#!/Queue">Queue</a>' + 
        '<a href="#!/Heap">Heap</a>' + 
        '<a href="#!/LinkedList">Linked List</a>' + 
      '</center>' + 
      '</div>',
    controller: function PageHeaderController() {

    }
  });
```

This way in index.html I can specify the  tag and have AngularJS fill out the DOM with the header HTML.

This works fine, but when I link in another script that defines the following controller:

```
angular.
  module('DataStructureVisualizer', []).
  controller('DragDropController', function DragDropController($scope) {
    $scope.captureCoordinate = function($event) {
      $scope.x = $event.x;
      $scope.y = $event.y;
    }
  });
```

The header disappears. What is the reason for this? I'm unsure on how to debug the application, as the Chrome JS console doesn't have any output and the NodeJS server isn't spitting out any errors (not sure why it would, as I'm not doing any server-side stuff, but thought that I should mention).

This is what my app.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('DataStructureVisualizer', [
  'ngRoute',
  'DataStructureVisualizer.bst',
  'DataStructureVisualizer.heap'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/BinaryTree'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `module('DataStructureVisualizer', [])` you're actually telling `angular` to consider it as a new `module` that's why it's not working coz you've already defined a module with the same name in your `app.js` file. You should change it to

```
angular.module('DataStructureVisualizer').controller('DragDropController', 
function DragDropController($scope) {
$scope.captureCoordinate = function($event) {
  $scope.x = $event.x;
  $scope.y = $event.y;
}
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I am curious, what are the square brackets for in the module definition? Are those dependencies that should be injected into the application?

Comment: yes. The dependencies of the module should be passed when module is being declared in an array, as a second argument of the module definition. And this should be one time. If you want to use this module anywhere else, to define `controller/service`, just use the name of the module and no `[]`